# How can I reset the network configuration of an Ubuntu partition that I can't boot into?

Tags: networking, network-manager, docker, network-bridge

I've been putting a lot of work into getting my new home server set up in the way that I'd like. I went with Ubuntu for a familiar GUI and creature comforts that come along with it, but it's basically meant to be a docker host. I've got a number of services running on it, some of which I'd like to expose to the outside world, so I've been working on a reverse proxy. I'm fairly new to Docker though, and I'm pretty sure I screwed this up real bad.

I've been trying to move some of my containers to a different subnet with a set of static IP addresses, and have been toggling between "host" and "bridge" networks through the process. One of my containers, I've noticed, which serves as a VPN tunnel for other services to leverage and uses the "host" network, has a way of changing the host computer's IP address and firewall settings, which I don't want, and have been trying to reconfigure away from. My way of getting through uncharted waters like these is - when tutorials or templates don't get you the result you want, just keep adjusting variables and trying different combinations of factors until I reveal or resolve the issue. Well, rebooted my computer last night when I noticed my samba shares on the machine were unreachable on the network, and my **OS won't boot**.

FWIW I used this guide as a framework for installing my OS: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019 - and I have done a fair amount of environment configuration, so I would prefer to not start from scratch. Everything at the system level has been humming along smoothly for a couple weeks now while I work out the kinks in exposing a reverse proxy web portal through my reserved domain.

After decrypting my boot partition, I get to the Ubuntu loading screen where it says "cryptsetup successful on (decrypted os partition name)" and after a few seconds it'll freeze or become completely unresponsive, ignoring SIGTERM and ctrl-alt-fX alike. If I attempt to boot in recovery mode, it drops to console output, becoming lethargic and eventually unresponsive (though it will respond to a SIGTERM emergency reboot). Any attmept to run fsck or mount drives fails.

The main factor I've been messing with, like I mentioned, is a variety of network settings. Internal/external DNS settings, IP addressing, firewall... It's a ball of yarn and I feel like my best chance at recovering this installation is to reset the network configuration from outside of the running OS.

I did back up most of the files from the OS partition using duplicity, I think. I managed to boot using a USB installation, mount the backup and the OS partition, wipe the /etc/ folder and restore it completely from backup, but it did not resolve the issue. Here is the output from /var/log/boot.log: https://pastebin.com/2Ci9dtEX

And here is the output from /var/log/syslog, back to last weekend (the 23rd) when the system/OS were completely fine, and including at the end some spam from my troubleshooting/recovery efforts: https://pastebin.com/sFScRTXf

How do I get back to good?

Comment: Welcome to AU. Partitions do not have network configs, and Ubuntu server has no GUI.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not running Ubuntu server, I thought a GUI would be easier to work with. With how I've been using it, I mostly didn't need it. But in any case, my installation does have a GUI. Linux stores representations of network connections and configuration on the OS filesystem partition. LAN identity, DNS settings, firewall and routing rules, for instance. That's what I mean when I say "network configuration".